# I want to offset high and low line in setting panel

Tags: pine-script, offset, orb

Hi i have find pine script in tv charting website

I want to change the coding to offset few points up and down of this lines in setting panel. original code is below if any one help me ?

```
//@version=4
study("ORB", overlay = true)

inputMax = input(5, title= "ORB total time (minutes)")
sess = input("0915-0920", type=input.session, title="Session Time") 
t = time(timeframe.period, sess + ":1234567")
hide = timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier <= inputMax

is_newbar(res) => change(time(res)) != 0
in_session = not na(t)
is_first = in_session and not in_session[1]

orb_high = float(na)
orb_low = float(na)

if is_first
    orb_high := high
    orb_low := low
else
    orb_high := orb_high[1]
    orb_low := orb_low[1]
if high > orb_high and in_session
    orb_high := high
if low < orb_low and in_session
    orb_low := low

plot(hide ? orb_high : na , style=plot.style_line, color=orb_high[1] != orb_high ? na : color.green, title="ORB High", linewidth=2)
plot(hide ? orb_low : na , style=plot.style_line, color=orb_low[1] != orb_low ? na : color.red, title="ORB Low", linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add two inputs to accept the offset of top and bottom bars.
Then add the offsets and plot new.
Example:

```
   //@version=4
study("ORB", overlay = true)
topoffset=input(0.5,title="Top Offset (%)",type=input.float)
bottomoffset=input(-0.5,title="Bottom Offset(%)",type=input.float)
inputMax = input(5, title= "ORB total time (minutes)")
sess = input("0915-0920", type=input.session, title="Session Time") 
t = time(timeframe.period, sess + ":1234567")
hide = timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier <= inputMax

is_newbar(res) => change(time(res)) != 0
in_session = not na(t)
is_first = in_session and not in_session[1]

orb_high = float(na)
orb_low = float(na)

if is_first
    orb_high := high
    orb_low := low
else
    orb_high := orb_high[1]
    orb_low := orb_low[1]
if high > orb_high and in_session
    orb_high := high
if low < orb_low and in_session
    orb_low := low

plot(hide ? orb_high : na , style=plot.style_line, color=orb_high[1] != orb_high ? na : color.green, title="ORB High", linewidth=2)
plot(hide ? orb_low : na , style=plot.style_line, color=orb_low[1] != orb_low ? na : color.red, title="ORB Low", linewidth=2)
plot(hide ? orb_high+topoffset*orb_high/100 : na , style=plot.style_line, color=orb_high[1] != orb_high ? na : color.green, title="ORB High", linewidth=1)
plot(hide ? orb_low+bottomoffset*orb_low/100 : na , style=plot.style_line, color=orb_low[1] != orb_low ? na : color.red, title="ORB Low", linewidth=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Agarwal sir, It is showing in setting panel as per i required exactly.

But this line showing top and bottom is not moving.

I hope you understand the idea is want to give some buffer points for first candle formed and to take entry once cross the butter line.

If possible we can keep original top and bottom line at original place, for entry we can add additional lines for buffer points 1%.

Can we work on this?

Comment: Edited my answer to add two additional lines with offset defined in percentage terms

Comment: awesome agarwal sir, perfect